Use an exisiting socket connection as proxy for http requests
The situation is, I wish to start a proxy server on the client side, and then the server side could use it as a proxy to connect to some third party serverices. However the client cannot expose it's IP and port. So I want to:

start the proxy server
connect to a remote service with socket.io
the remote service then use this socket connection to make http(s) requests

I was trying to use the createConnection option of http request, but how can I get the net.socket object from a socket.io socket object?
